# How to hinder Hibernate to change database

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

How can I make my database completely read-only for Hibernate? I don't want Hibernate to be able to change neither table definitions (e.g. create/delete/update tables) nor data in tables. Is there some setting in percictence.xml that makes connection read-only?

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate only does what's asked of it - if you set `hibernate.hbm2ddl` to auto | update | create | create-drop it will try to modify the DB schema. If you run an insert, it will try to insert data. If you want the DB to be protected against it, assign read-only permissions to the DB user that Hibernate is configured to use.